# Push Value of attribute in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function randomColor() {
    return 'rgb(' +
      Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ', ' +
      Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ', ' +
      Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ')'
  }

  $('.Showcolor #button').each(function(i) {
    $(this).css('background-color', randomColor());
  })
  var Random = [];
  var color = $(".Showcolor #button").css("background-color");
  for (i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    Random.push(color);
  }
  console.log(Random);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>captcha</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Click on circle matching right circle</h1>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="Showcolor">
      <button class="Black"></button>
      <button class="Blue"></button>
      <button class="Orange"></button>

      <button class="Pink"></button>
      <button class="Purple"></button>
      <button class="Skyblue"></button>

      <button class="Brown"></button>

    </div>
    <div="match">
      <button class="Random"></button>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="color" class="color" disabled>
  </div>
  <script src="jquery.3.js"></script>
  <script src="file.js"></script>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to store the color generated for each button into an array of colors(Random), so that an another button(class name = Random) can choose a color from this specific array. 
Can you help me to find a solution?

Comment: Multiple elements with the same ID in one document is **invalid HTML**. Fix that first.

Comment: ok then what about jquery

Comment: It's invalid when you're using jQuery as well.

Comment: Also variable names (eg. `var Random = [];` should be lowercase by convention to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the `id` attribute must be unique in the same document, so replace the duplicate ones by common class like :

```
<button class="button Black">Black</button>
<button class="button Blue">Blue</button>
<button class="button Orange">Orange</button>
```

You could use `map` to loop through them and push the colors to the array :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var buttons = $('.Showcolor .button');

  var Random = buttons.map(function(i) {
    var generated_color = randomColor();

    $(this).css('background-color', generated_color);

    return generated_color;
  }).get();

  $('.random').on('click', function() {
    $('.random').css('background-color', Random[Math.floor(Math.random() * Random.length)]);
  })
});

function randomColor() {
  return 'rgb(' +
    Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ', ' +
    Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ', ' +
    Math.round(Math.random() * 255) + ')'
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Click on circle matching right circle</h1>
<div class="box">
  <div class="Showcolor">
    <button class="button Black">Black</button>
    <button class="button Blue">Blue</button>
    <button class="button Orange">Orange</button>

    <button class="button Pink">Pink</button>
    <button class="button Purple">Purple</button>
    <button class="button Skyblue">Skyblue</button>

    <button class="button Brown">Brown</button>

  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="match">
    <button class="random">Random</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the IDs. Then instead of

```
$('.Showcolor #button').each(function(i) {
         $(this).css('background-color', randomColor());
      })
```

use

```
$('.Showcolor > button').each(function(i) {
         $(this).css('background-color', randomColor());
      })
```

to select all the `<button>` elements under the `Showcolor` `<div>`